# how to use mod:instance_method?

Tags: ruby

I made a small example code to make same thing as `"some string".methods` by using `instance_method`:

```
instance_method('methods').bind("some string").call
```

I don't know what's instance_method's receiver, so of course I got undefined methods error

What is the right way to use this method?

Answer (score 2):

`instance_method`'s receiver will be self for whatever context you are in. This is probably a mistake.

What you (presumably) want to do is give it the explicit receiver. In this case, the class that holds the methods for strings, the `String` class.

```
str   = "some string"
meths = String.instance_method('methods').bind(str)
meths == str.method('methods') # => true
meths.call # => [:<=>, :==, :===, ...etc... ]
```

You see? `"some string"` is an instance of `String`. So `String`'s instance methods are `"some string"`'s methods.